# Restore original text after changing it in a directive

Tags: angularjs, forms, parsing

I'm using a directive changing the text on a button to "please wait", "success" or "failure" when a form gets submitted. When the user changes a field, it gets restored to the original value.

I did it by storing the original value *just before setting it* using

```
$formElement.find("button").text();
```

Normally, it worked fine, but with a variable button text like

```
<button>{{(entity.id ? "update" : "create") | translate}}</button>
```

it fails as at the point I get the evaluated expression, i.e., either translated "update" or translated "create", but I'd need the expression.

So, I switched to doing it at the *beginning of the directive* and I get

```
{(entity.id ? "update" : "create") | translate}}
```

That's fine, but how can I evaluate it? I tried

```
 $parse(buttonText)
```

but it leads to

> angular.js:13236 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{(entity.id ? "update" : "create") | translate}}] starting at [{(entity.id ? "update" : "create") | translate}}].

I could strip the braces, but it could get more complicated with expressions like `Add {{item}} to {{list}}`, so the only clean method is using what angularjs uses. But what is it?

I'd also like to handle `ng-bind`, so that my directive is general.

Comment: I think you might be taking the more difficult way around by trying to change the element manually instead of manipulating the model or showing a message in a different part of markup saying "please wait".

Comment: @dwbartz Manipulating the model would imply adding something to the scope of all my forms and making all my buttons' text expression depend on it. It's surely simpler, but it's ugly and makes my directive only half as useful. A different area would be simple, too, but also repetitive. The button itself is IMHO the perfect place. +++ I'm rather sure, that the proper solution is not complicated, I'm just missing the right service.

Comment: @maartinus If you're wanting to change all buttons then I'd create a directive that uses transclusion and hides the button that you place the directive on when a form submit is in progress, which you track through a service.

Comment: @dwbartz But I want display not only "please wait", but also "success" and "failure" (which should disappear when the user changes something). Hiding the button would be fine otherwise, but I really like the idea of the button showing everything relevant. +++ The solution was trivial in the end: `$interpolate(buttonText)($scope)`, so I'm thinking about deleting my question soon.

Comment: @maartinus Create the directive with as many states as you want.  There's plenty of ways to do it, but if you're relying on manually setting the DOM you're probably going to have issues down the road since it's basically trying to get around Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was mixing up `$parse` and `$interpolate`. So the solution is to do

```
var buttonText = button.text();
```

at the beginning and

```
button.text($interpolate(buttonText)($scope));
```

to restore it.